# using prepared statements and fetchAll() to display to a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, code-injection

I'm trying to get my code SQL Injection safe, I am having trouble converting the pdo data to an array then comparing row data.

I have been reading up on [how to prevent sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) as well as [fetchAll() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and
[how to handle SELECT statements with pdo](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select).

Here is the relevant code. I believe it prepares the statement, then executes it, then the table is fetched and stored in $data where it is handed to $row, and then it looks up the player column and compares it with the logged in user to get the context based code to run. Where is the issue?

```php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM userdata");

$stmt->execute();

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>words</th>
</tr>";

while($row = $data)
{
echo $row['player'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['player'] . "</td>";
if($row['player'] == $logedInUsername)
{
    echo "<td>" . $row['words'] . "<a href='edityourword.php?edit=$row[words]'> edit</a></td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td>" . $row['words'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

My current error is reoccurring, here is the segment which the while loop keeps printing.

```
Notice: Undefined index: player on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: player on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: player on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: words on line 50

Notice: Undefined index: player on line 41

Notice: Undefined index: player on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: player on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: words on line 50
```

Comment: You probably want to use `foreach ( $data as $row)` instead of `while($row = $data)`

Comment: Strangely, the last page you linked to explains this very situation.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Even I didn't see it, I'm sorry.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was looking at that page for a good while, I just did not know the foreach method worked whereas the while loop was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got two options. Either change the while loop to a foreach loop as @NigelRen suggested or use [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method to fetch each record one by one from DB.

```
foreach ( $data as $row) {
    // ...
}
// or 
// Remove $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: what does ```$data = $stmt->fetchAll()``` do to $stmt.

```//$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))```

works whilst 

```$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))```

does not.

Comment: It fetches all the records matched in DB into a PHP array at once. [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). If you use `fetch` after it there are no more records to be read so it will not work.